# FileUpload and Retrieval

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I am trying to make a file upload page where users can upload an image or document to it and it to show up in a list fashion, I have managed to upload the image into a folder I created in my Project, but I have no idea how I'm meant to retrieve it, every time I try and search for it I get useless posts which don't really fit my question.

Here is my code:

```
    //
    // GET: /Upload/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(path);

        }

        Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", file);
    }
```

Comment: The standard practice for uploading files is to upload them to your directory, and at the same time, make an entry in a database to store the file path so that you can retrieve it later to print to the webpage.

Comment: @mituw16 that would probably be the ideal scenario but I can't seem to find anything that explains it, I know I need to turn it into a memory stream but how do I then put it into the database

Comment: You could go the way of store the actual bytes in the database if you want, but that is not what I was suggesting in my previous comment. All I was saying is try to modify your code so that it uploads exactly like it does now, then you just store the file name itself in a table. Later you just pull the file name from the database so you can do something with it.

Comment: @mituw16 my other idea was store the URL inside the database and the file in the directory, is that what you were getting at?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I was suggesting

Comment: @mituw16 I did try that but I don't know how to put the path into a textbox which would then insert into a database

Comment: Textbox? All you need to do is write a method in your model to accept a `string` parameter, which is the file name, that inserts into your db

Comment: @mituw16 Well on all other pages where I have input to database I have created the Create, Edit, Delete, Details and Index pages.

Becasue Originally I was just copying and pasting the link to the file into the create record page then inserting it to a database from there, but I have been told to make a file uploader, so this wont do anymore